# AngularJs with Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I used Asp.NET for the back end with Entity Framework 6 and tested it with fiddler and it works just fine with http methods, but when i use this, it does not work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp" >
<head>
    <title>My Client</title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="productController">

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>FirstName</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in result">
        <td>{{product.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{product.FirstName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <ul class="result">
        <li ng-repeat="product in result ">
            <span ng-bind ="product.Id"></span>
            <span ng-bind="product.FirstName"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('productController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:52068/api/employee').success(function (response) {
            $scope.result = response;
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error :**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:52068/api/employee. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:51078'; is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: What error you are getting? Check browser console for error.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:52068/api/employee. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:51078' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: can you put `api/employee` method also ?

Comment: I smell it as cross domain issue. Are you doing ajax across same domain or across different domains? If you are doing it across different domains then I will recommend you to go with CORS.